# How to grep dnszone from azure SQL Managed Instance connection-string

Tags: linux, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, az

**Requirement**: To automate the deployment of **azure sql mi** and connect the web application to it.
Everytime I create sql mi it generate a random "dnszone" which I am unable to capture in file which I need to create a connection string using bash command. below is sample scripts I have used:

```
$instanceName=sqlmi-poc
$dnszone=65r4897a552e <this i need to store>
jdbc:sqlserver://$instanceName.$dnszone.database.windows.net:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.$dnszone.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

I have tried couple of option available by unable to grep the $dnszone value

```
Get-AzSqlInstance -ResourceGroupName {rg-name} -Name {mi-name}
az sql mi list -g $rgp | grep "fullyQualifiedDomainName"
```

I appreciate any help to capture the dnszone value like this:

```
$dnszone="value"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
PS Azure:\> $dnszone =Get-AzSqlInstance -ResourceGroupName "rgouthindia" -Name "myinstancesouthindia*"

PS Azure:\> $dnszone.DnsZone
91d79b7f688b
```

Answer (score 0):

finally after working for hours there is solution and thought to share it.

```
x="az sql mi list -g $rgp | grep "fullyQualifiedDomainName";"

chksqlmi=$(eval "$x")

y=$(echo $chksqlmi | tr -d '"')

prefix="fullyQualifiedDomainName: $instanceName."

suffix=".database.windows.net,"

dnszone=$(echo $y | sed -e "s/^$prefix//" -e "s/$suffix$//")
```